# how to time.Parse() comma separate milliseconds in go

Tags: go, time

I have logs with timestamps that look like "2020-05-08 22:02:00,845".  They have comma separated milliseconds, which is what is giving time.Parse issues.  I can't seem to figure out how to make time.Parse happy with it.  Here is sample code that produces the error in go version go1.13.4 darwin/amd64 (and in the playground linked below);

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ts := "2020-05-08 22:02:00,845"
    _, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05,000", ts)
    print(err.Error())
}
```

Running that code produces this error

```
parsing time "2020-05-08 22:02:00,845" as "2006-01-02 15:04:05,000": cannot parse "845" as ",000"
```

Here a link to the code in the [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Bn1xXUKfiog)

So what would a format look like to parse this?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I doubt you can.

Comment: You can replace the comma with a period in the string and then parse.

Comment: With fractional seconds the decimal point is required, it's not exchangeable for other punctuation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug already filed [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6189)

The behaviour is documented as such: "A fractional second is represented by adding a period and zeros to the end of the seconds section of layout string, as in "15:04:05.000" to format a time stamp with millisecond precision.

Workaround for that would be replacing `","` with `"."`

package main

```
import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    ts := "2020-05-08 22:02:00,845"
    ts  =  strings.Replace(ts, ",", ".", -1)

    d, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000", ts)
    if err != nil{
        print(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

here is the [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4TlyQWMlgS1)

Comment: The bug you mentioned is treating it as a localization issue; in my case it is not.  I'm working with logs produced by log4j that are formatted this way.