# Go time.Parse Invalid ISO Date

Tags: go

Is there a way to parse the following date string using `time.Parse`:
`2023-06-06T07:04:58:278-07`?

I've attempted to use the format `2006-01-02T15:04:05:000Z07`, but the last `:` is causing  an error.

https://go.dev/play/p/y4T7meCX6D5

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61744098/how-to-time-parse-comma-separate-milliseconds-in-go) question may be relevant

Comment: `:` isn't a valid millisecond separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a `time.Parse` wrapper function to accept a decimal point, decimal comma, or colon as the seconds decimal separator.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

// Accept a decimal point, decimal comma, or colon
// as the seconds decimal separator.
func timeParse(layout, value string) (time.Time, error) {
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, value)
    if err == nil {
        return t, err
    }
    if strings.Count(value, ":") != 3 {
        return t, err
    }
    i := strings.LastIndexByte(value, ':')
    if i < 0 {
        return t, err
    }
    value2 := value[:i] + "." + value[i+1:]
    t2, err2 := time.Parse(layout, value2)
    if err2 == nil {
        return t2, err2
    }
    return t, err
}

func main() {
    inDate := "2023-06-06T07:04:58:278-07"
    parseFormat := "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07"
    t, e := timeParse(parseFormat, inDate)
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/bjk8sw5yL78

```
2023-06-06 07:04:58.278 -0700 -0700
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `:` is not a valid separator for fractional seconds. The only two allowed separators are the `.` and the `,` as suggested by @rocka2q. I changed your example accordingly and I was able to parse the incoming datetime.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    inDate := "2023-06-06T07:04:58,158-07" // it works with the comma
    // inDate := "2023-06-06T07:04:58.158-07" // it works with the dot
    // inDate := "2023-06-06T07:04:58:158-07" // ":" is not a valid separator for the fractional seconds. Only "." is allowed
    parseFormat := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-07"

    t, err := time.Parse(parseFormat, inDate)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

This is also confirmed by these two Pull Requests:

- [PR1](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6189#issuecomment-646003868)
- [PR2](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36145)

Let me know if this solves your issue, thanks!

Comment: In this case, the 278 is intended to be milliseconds and it can vary and is not always constant.

Comment: answer just edited, let me know thanks!

Comment: Nice find with the PRs.  Unfortunately the answer you provided while works for the inDate in your example, doesn't work with "2023-06-06T07:04:58:278-07"

Comment: @ossan: "The only allowed separator is the `.`". That is no longer true, starting with Go 1.17: "either a comma or a decimal point followed by a maximal series of digits is parsed as a fractional second." https://pkg.go.dev/time